# Не могу подключиться к PostgreSql через GORM на Golang

Tags: postgresql, golang, orm

C чем может быть связано, что через GORM нет доступа к базе PostgreSQL, а в PgAdmin- есть. Настройки одинаковые. Антивирус, брандмауер выключил. GORM перекачал по новой.

```
   import(
        //"github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
      "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
      _ "github.com/lib/pq"
   )
```

Сам код подключения

```
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost:5432  user=postgres password=RomanRakzin dbname=MyDB  sslmode=disable")  
    if err != nil {
       log.Println("Ошибка подключения к базе данных......") 
    }
```

Причём я пробовал и без указания `host=localhost:5432` и просто `host=localhost`.
База есть,пользователь с таким паролем-тоже. Всё работает в PgAdmin, а здесь-нет.

Comment: Как на счёт всё-таки посмотреть в `err`, а не просто проверить что он есть? .-.

Comment: pq: unexpected error: "setting PGLOCALEDIR not supported"

Answer (score 2):

Я бы попробовал раскомментить строку с импортом

`//"github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"`

на

`_ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"`

Ещё вы можете попробовать логгировать и саму ошибку тоже, а не только её наличие. Т.е. заменить строку

`log.Println("Ошибка подключения к базе данных......")`

на, например:

`log.Printf("Ошибка подключения к базе данных: %s", err)`

Comment: err =   pq: unexpected error: "setting PGLOCALEDIR not supported"

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать `_ "github.com/lib/pq"` - насколько я понимаю, импорт этого драйвера для открытия соединения в gorm не нужен. Либо можете попробовать убрать переменную PGLOCALEDIR. pq кидает ошибку, если выставлена какая-то неподдерживаемая переменная. Убрать переменную можно командой `unset PGLOCALEDIR`

Comment: @"Pavel Kazhevets" Если закомментирую- не работает. А где прописать unset PGLOCALEDIR? (у меня винда)

Comment: Писал вариант для линукса. С виндой можете попробовать вариант(ы) отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration

Answer (score -1):

Я решил свою проблему на Windows удалением из переменных среды записи `PGLOCALEDIR` и всё заработало.